# ¿Como remplazar una imagen al actualizar un registro con PHP?

Tags: php, fileupload

Estoy intentando actualizar un registro de mi BD, dicho registro cuenta con una imagen, esta imagen la imagen que el usuario selecciona cuando se va a registrar.

Lo que quiero hacer es remplazar la imagen que esta en mi directorio por una nueva, esto para que no se cruce información y también para que no este lleno de imágenes del mismo usuario mi directorio.

Este es el código donde actualizo, en este caso me agrega una imagen nueva, ya que se renombra en una parte del código php. ¿Como podría realizar esto?

Codigo php:

```
    public function updUser($infoUpd, $file)
    {   

        $conexion = new Connection();
        $pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
        $photo = $file['name'];
        $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $directorio_destino = "images";
        $img_size = $file['size'];
        $img_type = $file['type'];

        $upload_dir = '../../imgs/profile/'; // upload directory 

        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($photo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); //get image extension

        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extension 

        $userpic = rand(1000, 1000000).".".$imgExt; //rename uploading image

        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){

            if ($img_size < 1000000) {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir.$userpic);
            }else{
            $error_message = "<script>alert('Su archivo de imagen es muy grande, solo se permite 1MB'); location.href='../index.php';</script>";
            echo $error_message;
            }
        }else{
            $error_message = "<script>alert('Solo archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF son permitidos'); location.href='../index.php';</script>";
            echo $error_message;
        }

                if (!isset($error_message)) {

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET name = :name, email = :email, photo = :photo WHERE id_user = :id_user");
        $statement->bindValue('id_user', $infoUpd['id_userEdit']);
        $statement->bindValue('name', $infoUpd['nameEdit']);
        $statement->bindValue('email', $infoUpd['emailEdit']);
        $statement->bindValue('photo', $userpic);
        $res = $statement->execute();

        if($res)
        {
            //header("Location: ../usuarios.php");
            echo"<script>alert('¡Usuario actualizado con exito!'); location.href='adminusers.php';</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script>alert('Hubo un error'); location.href='adminusers.php';</script>";
        }
       
    }

}
```

Esta este es el código actualizado:

```
public function updUser($infoUpd, $file)
{
    $conexion = new Connection();
    $pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
    $photo = $file['name'];
    $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
    $directorio_destino = "images";
    $img_size = $file['size'];
    $img_type = $file['type'];

    $upload_dir = '../../imgs/profile/'; // upload directory

    $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($photo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); //get image extension

    $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extension

    $userpic = rand(1000, 1000000).".".$imgExt; //rename uploading image

    if (in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)) {
        if ($img_size < 1000000) {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir.$userpic);
        } else {
            $error_message = "<script>alert('Su archivo de imagen es muy grande, solo se permite 1MB'); location.href='../index.php';</script>";
            echo $error_message;
        }
    } else {
        $error_message = "<script>alert('Solo archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF son permitidos'); location.href='../index.php';</script>";
        echo $error_message;
    }

    if (!isset($error_message)) {
        $qFotoAnterior = $pdo->prepare("SELECT photo FROM users WHERE id_user = :id_user");
        $qFotoAnterior->bindValue('id_user', $infoUpd['id_userEdit']);
        $resultado = $qFotoAnterior->execute();
        $foto_anterior = $resultado->fetch()[0];

        if (file_exists($upload_dir.$foto_anterior)) {
            unlink($upload_dir.$foto_anterior);
        }

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET name = :name, email = :email, photo = :photo WHERE id_user = :id_user");
        $statement->bindValue('id_user', $infoUpd['id_userEdit']);
        $statement->bindValue('name', $infoUpd['nameEdit']);
        $statement->bindValue('email', $infoUpd['emailEdit']);
        $statement->bindValue('photo', $userpic);
        $res = $statement->execute();

        if ($res) {
                //header("Location: ../usuarios.php");
            echo"<script>alert('¡Usuario actualizado con exito!'); location.href='adminusers.php';</script>";
        } else {
            echo"<script>alert('Hubo un error'); location.href='adminusers.php';</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como tienes el código, la única forma posible es conociendo el nombre de la imagen anterior, la cual puedes descubrir así:

```php
$qFotoAnterior = $pdo->prepare("SELECT photo FROM users WHERE id_user = :id_user");
$qFotoAnterior->bindValue('id_user', $infoUpd['id_userEdit']);
$qFotoAnterior->execute();
$resultado = $qFotoAnterior->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$foto_anterior = $resultado['photo'];
```

y luego eliminarla del directorio mediante:

```php
if(is_file($upload_dir.$foto_anterior)) {
    unlink($upload_dir.$foto_anterior); 
} else {
    echo "No se ha encontrado la foto anterior. Revisar la ruta, gracias: '.$upload_dir.$foto_anterior; 
}
```

Esto debes ponerlo **solo** si la nueva imagen está bien subida, para evitar borrar una imagen que aun está en la base de datos, y **antes** de la consulta del UPDATE, sino borrarás la imagen recien subida. Es decir, ponlo debajo de esta línea:

```php
if (!isset($error_message)) {
```

Ya nos contarás si te funciona.

Comment: A ti, saludos! :-)